# One prerequisite folder for multiple installers

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, prerequisites

I have several InstallShield basic MSI projects that have custom prerequisite (let's call it MY_PREREQ).

MY_PREREQ has size ~200MB, so it would be nice do not include it in every setup.exe. I want to place it in some "shared" folder instead, and all installers should look at this folder and run MY_PREREQ if needed. How can I do it in InstallShield 2013 Professional? Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

The .PRQ has a GUID identifier and when you build the setup.exe with the option of "copy prereqs from folder" (or something like that)  it creates a structure with setup.exe  {GUID} and inside of their your prereq content.

You can then build all your setup.exe's (with different setup.exe filenames) and then merge all of the content into a single structure.    Each installer should find it's content if it needs it to install.

Comment: if I set 'Copy from Source Media', it will create the following structure: ISSetupPrerequisites\{MY_PREREQ_GUID}\MY_PREREQ.exe. But here's another question - can I set relative path to ISSetupPrerequisites folder manually in InstallShield solution? Suppose, I have 2 folders: product1 and product2. Each of them contains setup.exe. I want to create 3-rd folder  - ISSetupPrerequisites - on the same level as product1 and product2. But installers won't find prereqisites in this case, because it tries to find ISSetupPrerequisites folder on the same folder where setup.exe is placed.

Comment: no, you'll have to put all the installers in the same root directory.  Suite Installers might have more flexibility here, I haven't tried.  Otherwise you would have to write your own boostrapper/chainer.